# names for SMT ribbon cable socket types

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

whats the name of the type of ribbon cable socket used in laptops? or what would I look under to find them on a site like farnell?

Its some thing like a D-Sub connect to system, except the plug is actually moulded onto the cabling at 90 degrees to it and the plug and socket are very low profile.
It is the connector on the left in the below pic

[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it's molded, but usually it will be soldered, just like any other PCB. [Hirose](http://www.hirose-connectors.com/connectors/H216boardtoboardconnectors.aspx?p1=1) lists some of these **board-to-board connectors**.
[JST](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/search_e.php?type=1&id=3&page=1) also makes low-profile board-to-board connectors.

Comment: JST makes a lot of these types of connectors and they are very friendly about providing samples

Answer (score 2):

Brown part on the photo is a *flex circuit*, rather than ribbon cable.  The connector on the photo belongs to a broad class of FFC/FPC connectors.  Usually, large suppliers like Farnell, [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Connectors/FFC-FPC/_/N-axjog/), DigiKey have a category for this class of connectors.

FPC - Flexible Printed Circuits
FFC - Flat Flexible Cable