# FFC/FPC that locks directly onto PCB?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable, ffc

Does anyone have any recommendations for an FFC/FPC connector that locks the flex cable contacts directly to pads on the PCB rather than the connector bed?
I am trying to get a VERY low inductance connection system sorted.

Ta

Comment: Doesn't the answer to [your other question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31960/names-for-smt-ribbon-cable-socket-types) help? Some of those board-to-board connectors are only 0.4mm high. They should have low inductance.

Comment: @stevenh Ta, yes that helps some, but I want to check out several options, if something like this exists it would probably be better again.

Answer (score 1):

There are heat sealed flex cables that can be attached directly to a PCB using conductive heat-activated adhesive, however they cannot be removed after being attached and the assembly equipment recommended for reliable joints is not cheap.

If you are satisfied with one-time connection, I would suggest looking at rigid-flex PCBs where the flex and rigid portions are manufactured together.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably a bad idea to try to make a contact between a FFC/FPC cable and a coppertrace on a PCB directly.

- It will be difficult to have a constant pressure on the contacts. Forces from springs on top of the FFC will accumulate as a line load, bending away a molded housing at the middle of the FFC cable, as it has no mechanical counterpart.
- Copper track surfaces probably must be gold plated to be even enough for a constant pressing force.
- The housing needs to get its counter force from soldered housing contacts applying continuos stress on the solder and copper tracks.

I guess, you won't find a connector for these causes.

You better go for a board-in solution.

I found this one here: [FUN FFC/FPC board in connector](http://file:///Users/moritzkaiser/Downloads/pitch-1-0-mm-board-in-fun-pdf.pdf)

I have seen board-in crimp style connectors at TE's booth at productronica some years ago, but I'm unable to find them at the moment.

Comment: your link refers to a local file on your computer.